# How to initialize a field from another class?

Tags: c#, list, class, initialization, console-application

The method I tried is like this:

```
//first class
public class First()
{
  public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
}


//second class
public class Second()
{
  First initial = new First();
  List<Item> newItem = initial.Items;
}
```

But when I use newItem, I lose access to the data stored in Items, How can I access the data in Items from another class and perform operations on it?

Comment: Initialize in the Constructor of `Second()` -- You probably don't need `newItem` - Consider Properties. Then as above (unless it's a typo)

Comment: @Desko You should use Add and Remove to perform operation on List.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: what is your actual problem?

Comment: this code does not even compile. please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Make the first class Static.

```
public static class First()
{
  public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
}


//second class
public class Second()
{
  First.Items = <<somedata>>;
  List<Item> newItem = First.Items;
}
```